# uninitialized constant ReviewsController::Reviews

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, activerecord, has-one

I had this working very similar to another controller however i needed to change this relation to another controller called `agreements_controller`. I want to create a has one model. `review has one and belongs to agreements`.

Why isn't the row being created properly?

reviews_controller:

```
class ReviewsController < ApplicationController

  def create
     @review = Reviews.create(review_params)
  end


  private

  def review_params
    params.require(:review).permit(:comment, :star, :agreement_id, :user_id, :reviser_user_id)
  end

end
```

_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for([agreement, agreement.build_review] ) do |f| %>

<% end %>
```

agreement.rb

```
class Agreement < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :review, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

review.rb

```
class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :agreement   
  belongs_to :reviser_user
  belongs_to :user
end
```

I've tried to find similar examples online, but all I could find was nested forms... I don't need a nested form I just want the review to create as a has one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Models are Singular**. Use

```
Review.create(review_params)
```

Comment: I wouldn't say that models are singular as much as _his_ model in particular is singular. If you look, his code sample above even proves that `Review` is his class name.

Comment: Models are not always Singular?

Comment: not always, but by default they are. They can be forcibly generated as plural with `--force-plural`. In this case, the "true" answer is that _his_ model as shown above is singular, so his controller should call it as his code reads.